# Formula to create row for each month between start and end dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of projects (a data set) which looks like:

```
Project        Start     End       Allocation
----------------------------------------------
Example A      3/2019     8/2019          60%
Example B      5/2019     8/2019          30%
Example C      3/2019    12/2019          10%
```

My goal is to create a stacked column chart with this data. For example:

[image: Example chart]

I think I need to have a data point for each month. For example, **Example B** has a row for May, June, July, and August. For my chart above, I have created individual data points and then created a pivot chart based on that data.

Is there a formula (preferably) or macro which can create those data points / rows for each month between the start and end date? The start and end dates may change, which adds some complexity.

Or perhaps I do not need to create individual data points.

Comment: It's not clear what you want your chart to be, but in any case, your assumption that you need to have a data point for each month is probably wrong. It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of what the chart should look like

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have added an example of the chart I'm trying to create. Right now, it's created via individual data points and a pivot chart.

Answer (score 1):

1. make a new table with "Example A", "Example B", "Example C"  as the labels for the columns and the months as the labels for the rows
2. Put the following formula in the top left cell:

   ```
   =IF(AND($A9>=VLOOKUP(D$8,$A$2:$D$4,2),$A9<=VLOOKUP(D$8,$A$2:$D$4,3)),VLOOKUP(D$8,$A$2:$D$4,4),"")
   ```
3. Populate the whole table with the formula

You will be able to generate a stacked column chart with it:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind updating your image to include row numbers? I set the table up the same and copied the formula, but I'm getting #N/A errors.

Comment: The headers on my table were on row `8`. The selected cell is `B9`. I assumed your data table was in `A1:D4`